# Error with "lowess" function in R

Tags: r, smoothing, regression

I have a problem with lowess function to smooth NDVI as a time in R. Here is the scripts I run:

```
#Create a time vector to act as x
time<-sort(sample(97:297, nlayers(ndvi2000crop1)))

#locally-weighted polynomial regression of ndvi ~ time
t.lowess <- function(x,...) { if (is.na(x[1])) {NA} else {lowess(x,y,...)$y } } 
f.pred <- calc(ndvi2000crop1, t.lowess)
```

When I calculate the function on image, an error appeared something like this "Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply): cannot use this function". Can you tell me where this error comes from in this part?

Comment: Before calculating this, I have just read images as single layers and stacked them. Then a small section of stacked image has been cropped by small extent to text the code. This cropped small section is being used for the calculation of this script. Can these read and crop function effect on the calculation?

Comment: Please link to a sample of your data.